# Regional formats are set to German while file managers still show English formats

Tags: language-support, locale

Although I am Austrian, I prefer to use Ubuntu in English, while of course I do not want to miss my regional formats.

These are the current settings in `/etc/default/locale`:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_AT.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_AT.UTF-8"
```

And this is a screenshot of dolphin:

[image]

It shows American time formats. In Nautilus, time format lacks the year when the file was saved/created in current year and so on.

There does not seem to be a pattern on how applications show the date/time. Also finding some switch in the preferences of the respective application was in vain.

Only the date and time in the upper right hand corner of unity is correct. How come?

Comment: Please show us the output of the `locale` command.

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Answer (score 0):

The `locale` output looks normal. The Nautilus behavior you describe is intended, I think, but there seems to be a Dolphin bug.

Dolphin is a qt application, right? In that case, it wouldn't be the first qt app I have encountered with this particular bug.

One thing you may want to try is to create the file `~/bin/dolphin`, give it this contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=de_AT.UTF-8
export LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
exec /usr/bin/dolphin $@
```

and give it execution rights:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/dolphin
```

That file works as a wrapper when you start Dolphin. However, there is a risk that not only the formats, but also the display language, will be switched to German...

Comment: Thanks for your input, but how would I execute that chmod +x command. I am stll a newbie to Linux/Ubuntu. Further I have these problems also in the file manager krusader as well as in the Libre office suite, where cell heights and widths are shown in inch. I want to stick to English as it is the original language, but if these problems persist I would rather set LC_ALL=de_AT.UTF-8.

Comment: @NikolausHaydu: I clarified my answer re the chmod command. LibreOffice has its own interface for controlling the language.